# Why is a GeoTIFF uploaded to MapBox as a tileset shown in black and white and not the original colors in the TIFF?

Tags: mapbox

When uploading a GeoTIFF file to Mapbox to create a tileset, it is being displayed in Black and White? I would expect it to have the same colors as the TIFF when viewed in any other viewer?

How do you create a tileset with a GeoTIFF to use it as a base map in MapBox?

My ultimate goal is to use this GeoTIFF and then dynamically lay lat/long points on it, but I need to get the map looking correct first.

Seems to work just fine in QGIS.

Comment: Is your GeoTIFF using RGB bands or is it a single band with indexed/palatte colours? You might need to expand it to RGB. See gdal_translate's -expand option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following commands can be used to translate the GeoTIFF file. This information was obtained by MapBox support.

1. this will leave you with a raster tile with a black background.

`gdal_translate -co TILED=TRUE -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -expand RGB INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif`

2. Make your raster tile transparent

`rio calc "(asarray (take a 1) (take a 2) (take a 3))" --co compress=lzw --co tiled=true --co blockxsize=256 --co blockysize=256 --name a=INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif`

3. Make NoData values to zero.

`rio edit-info --nodata 0 INPUT.tif`

Before Conversion

[image]

After Conversion
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using R / raster package for this, you need to do two things:

1. Set `colNA` option of `RGB` to "black".
2. On raster write, set `NAflag` to 0.

For instance:

```
library(raster)

rgb_raster <- RGB(a_raster, colNA='black')

# Not sure if these are needed, but match the official example
options = c("COMPRESS=LZW", "BIGTIFF=YES", "TILED=TRUE", "BLOCKXSIZE=256",
            "BLOCKYSIZE=256")

writeRaster(rgb_raster, 
    filename='rgb_raster.tif', 
    datatype='INT1U',
    NAflag=0,
    options=options)
```

The `writeRaster` call needs to be done separate from the `RGB` call because an error results if you set `datatype` there.